# Node limit module

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

Is there any one which have used [node limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit/) module? I have problem with this module. It does not work and every time accessing to content is denied.

Comment: version of drupal?  if 6, I've had good success with the node_limitnumber module:  http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber

Comment: my drupal version is 7

Comment: Node limit works fine for me in a couple of production sites, can you specific about the problem you're having?

Comment: I have created a CCK based form and put it on my menu. Without node limit authenticated users could access to this menu link, but after setting Node limit "Access denied" message is appeared.

Comment: you have solved this issue?